# Basic PHP syntax for editing a Wordpress social sharing plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter

I'm trying to edit a social sharing plugin, to change the link/text show in the popups for twitter, etc..

Basically when it clicks to share on Twitter, it displays the page title and current URL on a thank you page, I want to customize it to display certain text and a different URL. Tried changing the `&url=<?php echo $url; ?>` part to `&url=<?php http://www.urltext.com; ?>` for example but doesn't work, how can I edit this so the syntax is proper?

```
case 'twitter':
    ?><a rel="external nofollow" class="ss-twitter" href="http://twitter.com/intent/tweet/?text=<?php echo $title; ?>&url=<?php echo $url; ?><?php if(!empty($twitter_username)) {  echo '&via=' . $twitter_username; } ?>" target="_blank"><span class="ss-icon-twitter"></span><?php echo $twitter_text; ?></a> <?php
break;
```

Comment: How in the world is this unclear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax is incorrect. You'll want to use:

```
&url=<?php echo 'http://www.urltext.com'; ?>
```

The url is a string; so you need to echo it as a string.